# ComponentDidUpdate firing multiple time instead of once per update

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My component is performing calculation based on the result from before user performs a change, and afterwards, and for some reason, the component seems to be running the function multiple times instead of once per change, which is resulting in inaccurate results. Any suggestion on what could be causing the problem?

This is the code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { ILiquidiManagerProps } from './ILiquidiManagerProps';
import {AccountValue} from './AccountFields';
import {LiquidTEUR} from './DummyContent';

interface SubtotalState {
    Account?: any,
    SubtotalValue?: any,
    iteration?: number,
  }

export default class SubtotalValues extends React.Component<ILiquidiManagerProps, SubtotalState> {
    public constructor(props: ILiquidiManagerProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Account: LiquidTEUR.Subcategories.find(item => item.Name == this.props.label),
            SubtotalValue: 0,
        }
    }
    
    private getText = data => {
        this.setState({SubtotalValue: data});
    }

    private initiateValue = () => {
        let Account = this.state.Account;
        let subtotal = 0;
        Account.Accounts.map((item) => {
            subtotal += item.Value;
        })
        this.setState({SubtotalValue: subtotal});
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.initiateValue();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(_prevProps, prevState){
        if (this.state.SubtotalValue !== prevState.SubtotalValue){
            let total = this.props.liquidTotal;
            if(this.props.label == 'Kreditlinien in TEUR'){
                total = total + prevState.SubtotalValue - this.state.SubtotalValue;
            } else {
                total = total - prevState.SubtotalValue + this.state.SubtotalValue;
            }
            this.props.getValue(total);
        }
    }

    public render(): React.ReactElement<ILiquidiManagerProps> {
        console.log(this.props.liquidTotal + "Subtotal");
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
            <a className="collapsible" href="#">
                <div 
                    className={`p-2 text-right value ` + this.props.bgColor + ` font-weight-bold ` + this.props.textColor}
                    data-date={this.props.date}
                    data-name={this.props.label}
                >{this.state.SubtotalValue.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ".")}</div></a>
            <div className="content hidden">
                {this.state.Account.Accounts.map((item, key) => {
                    return <AccountValue key={key} label={item.Value} getValue={this.getText} subtotal={this.state.SubtotalValue} />;
                })}
                <span className="add-pos">&nbsp;</span>
            </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Well if you update the props or state from within componentDidUpdate it Will obviously get called again...

Comment: But the event should only occur if the value of the SubtotalValue is different from the previous one, hence the if statement.

Comment: Can you post the ILiquidiManagerProps props and what LiquidTEUR is? Maybe a sandbox with all the code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the problem. The getText function is getting values from another component, which initiates as 0, but then receives another value from another component. The delay is causing the state to update, and since the values are different, the componentDidUpdate fired at initialization.

I used an async function on ComponentWillMount in the other component, which seems to have solved the issue:

```
async componentWillMount(): Promise<void> {
    this.LiquidTotal();
}
```